# How should I make API calls in React container components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a `React Redux` application in which I have a whole load of state items in the store. I have actions set up to populate the state from my back end API. I use container and presentational components and in my container I am getting all the state I require for its children using `mapDispatchToProps`, and then passing the state down as props using `mapStateToProps`.

Currently this is how I'm making those initial API calls in my container component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getResources()
        .then(() => {
            this.props.getUsers()
                .then(() => {
                    this.props.getComments()
                        .then(() => {
                            this.props.getFiles()
                                .then(() => {
                                    this.props.getAlts()
                                        .then(() => {
                                            this.props.getSubjects()
                                                .then(() => {
                                                    this.props.getTemplates()
                                                        .then(() => {
                                                            this.props.getResourceTags()
                                                                .then(() => {
                                                                    this.setState({
                                                                        resourcesLoaded: true
                                                                    });
                                                                });
                                                        });
                                                });
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

Which just seems ridiculous. Is there a cleaner way to make these API requests or refactor my actions so that they are condensed in to a single action?

Comment: Consider using `Promise.all`, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Why create so many separate promise chains? You could flatten it all out to `this.props.getResources().then(() => this.props.getUsers()).then(...)` or, given that you don't need the previous resutls for the next step, use `Promise.all([this.props.getResources(), this.props.getUsers(), ...]).then(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way it to run all functions/promises concurrently using `Promise.all`

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        this.props.getResources(),
        this.props.getComments(),
        this.props.getFiles(),
        this.props.getAlts(),
        this.props.getSubjects(),
        this.props.getTemplates(),
        this.props.getResourceTags()
    ]).then(() =>
        this.setState({ resourcesLoaded: true })
    )
}
```

The benefit of using `Promise.all` over `await` is that `await` runs every function/promise serially while `Promise.all` runs all functions concurrently.

**Detailed Explanation**

So when we use

```
await getResources()
await getComments()
...
...
```

the `await` keyword will wait for `getResources()` to finish and then it will run `getComments()` and wait for its completion and this will go on.

While using `Promise.all`, it will run all the functions at once and will wait until every function is executed and only then will run the `.then(...)` part.

Comment: What is the reason for making componentDidMount an async function?

Comment: Hey @Tehloltractor , it is there because we used `await` in that function (which is not required actually, removing this now.). Thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 3):

You can use `async - await` instead of callback pattern. This is an ES6 feature.

Example:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        await this.props.getResources()
        await this.props.getComments()
        await this.props.getFiles()
        await this.props.getAlts()
        await this.props.getSubjects()
        await this.props.getTemplates()
        await this.props.getResourceTags()
        this.setState({
            resourcesLoaded: true
        })
    } catch (e) {
        // in case any function above causes error
    }
}
```